# What exactly is DayTum?

Tags: website

I try and I try, but I still have no idea what [DayTum](http://daytum.com/) is. I like the idea of [a quantified self](http://www.ted.com/talks/gary_wolf_the_quantified_self.html), but it seems to be the most impossible thing to implement even though numbers are so darn easy to track.

Can somebody explain to me the concept of DayTum and how I would use it, to say, track when I go to bed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is personal page with self-motivation statistics and texts.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of DayTum is to present your data, or numbers as you say, in a more visual way. You can use DayTum to manage your expenses and track your progress in anything you can think of actually. Say you're an alcoholic trying to get sober, you can track the days you last drank alcohol.